# Which camera should I buy: 7d or 70d?

Tags: camera-recommendation, canon-7d, wedding, outdoor, canon-70d

I had a Nikon D3100 camera. I want to upgrade it. Can anyone help me choose between a Canon 7d or 70d? I want it for outdoor, wedding and studio photography.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42543/seriously-considering-upgrading-my-rebel-t2i-550d-to-either-a-6d-7d-or-70d

Comment: Have you researched these two bodies?  At least looked at something like  http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon-EOS-70D-vs-Canon_EOS_7D ? Do you know the differences?  Which of those differences are important to you?   We can't know which camera is better for you - it's a very personal and subjective choice.

Comment: Neither. For wedding and commercial studio photography you really need a full frame body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, I do not answer to such questions because they are subject to (extensive) discussion and the final "answer" is rather a subjective decision.

However in this very case and in this very moment it is different.

Disclaimer: I'm Canon shooter from enough years, I'm pretty satisfied with my equipment - I have also Nikon, Sony and Hasselblad. No, I don't religiously say that Canon is the savior of the (photographic) world.

Answer #1: **Never, ever, ever buy something before doing your (future) market research/analysis.**

Answer #2: **Never, ever, ever buy a model when a big successor is announced with fanfare.**

In your concrete case [it is known](http://www.canonrumors.com/2014/07/eos-7d-replacement-telephoto-lens-in-september-cr3/) from enough sources that mid-august, start of september [shortly before Photokina](http://www.canonrumors.com/2014/07/eos-7d-mark-ii-announcement-date-september-5-2014/) (September, this year) the successor of 7D will be announced. [Amazon already has already 7D as discontinued](http://www.canonrumors.com/forum/index.php?topic=21954.msg417996;topicseen#new) thing which confirms once more that 7D Mk 2 (or whatever it will be called) is around here.

There [are quite impressive patents](http://www.canonrumors.com/2014/06/patent-canon-5-layer-uv-ir-rgb-sensor/) from Canon issued now and with together with these patents internal(?) sources say that it will be ["the biggest change in Canon's history"](http://www.canonwatch.com/whatever-canon-going-announce-august-will-ship-october/).

For me (and for many others IMHO) it is quite clear that 7D's successor will be/is a corner-stone in Canon's history, because:

- it is/was awaited for a looong time. Canon must show that it was worth the wait.
- Canon has now the bad reputation of lagging in sensor tech & innovation. It isn't entirely true IMHO, but anyway Canon now must prove that they're the best.
- Canon already made known through above 'leaks' (when Craig from Canon Rumors marks a rumor as CR3 this means that we must treat the rumor as a fact) that the next camera will be *'the biggest change in Canon's history yada yada yada'*. Canon must make sure that this change is a good one and not a bad one.

From all these things and (not only) the camera to be announced will be a very big thing (good - I hope - or bad). This means that:

- the prices of the old models will fall (sometimes a lot)
- you'll read a lot of reviews, opinions and user comments about the new model (of course) but also about the company's future. Also you'll know where the market is heading.
- you/we'll see new technologies which make us more knowledgeable in order to decide what to buy: 70D, 7D, 6D or the new 7D Mk2.

So in short, answer #3: **If you can afford it, WAIT A LITTLE.**

Comment: I appreciate the effort but unless you work for Canon I don't like this answer. This isn't a rumor mill :)

Comment: @dpollitt Normally I would agree with you on this. But when Canon Rumors marks something as "CR3" it almost always means the source *is* an high level employee at Canon and rarely, if ever, has a CR3 level rumor turned out not to be spot on. I think you can take the *7D mark II* being announced sometime early this Fall to the bank.

Comment: @John Thomas On the other hand, prices for the 7D have already plummeted. You can pick up a grey market copy from a reputable seller for around $800US. You can also currently get a refurbished 7D direct from Canon USA for $719.52 (Canon does add sales tax based on the shipping address).